# Impossible to remove data

Tags: r, import, environment, workspace

I noticed that even after clearing the environment, clearing the workspace and uninstalling R, I still can't get rid of old variables that still show up.

Here is how I launch my database:

```
#rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))



stim<-read.table(file.choose(),header=T)
attach(stim)
names(stim)
summary(stim)
str(stim$emotionT2)
names(stim)
```

I tried removing the "attach(stim)" line, but then none of the newly imported dataset works.

How can I completely clear all data to make sure that I am really testing the newly imported one?

Comment: Please don't include `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))` in your posted code without commenting it out. People might accidentally copy it and run it.

Comment: Good advice is to never use `attach`. You can use `with` which is like a temporary version of `attach`. There is also `detach`, which attempts to undo the results of a previous `attach`, but best not to get involved.

Comment: Do you have any .Rdata files in your home directory?

Comment: Thanks, I used `#detach(stim, pos=2L, unload=FALSE, character.only = FALSE, force=FALSE)` which worked to get rid of the old variables. However, after importing a dataset I still cannot call the variables. I probably misused the `with` function.

Comment: @Dason Yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Delete any `.RData` files in your working directory (your home directory, if you aren't sure).  If you want to be careful, just move them/rename them rather than deleting.